# swagger-ui doesn't display the response model for a 400

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

Here is an extract of my generated swagger doc.

```
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "successful operation",
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/ActionJsValue"
        }
      },
      "400": {
        "description": "list of validation errors",
        "schema": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Error"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

And in the definition part :

```
"Error": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "path": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "messages": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
},
```

And swagger-ui doesn't display the response model.

Anyone encounters this issue ?
Anyone knows how to fix that ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered exactly the same issue and found the next workaround.

Method description:

```
"responses": {
  "200": {
    "description": "successful operation",
    "schema": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/ActionJsValue"
    }
  },
  "400": {
    "description": "list of validation errors",
    "schema": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/ErrorsArray"
    }
  }
}
```

Definition part:

```
"ErrorsArray": {
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "path": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "messages": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, just define your array as separate type.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Whaterver the url you have used for generated swagger doc, the same url you need to use in the swagger-ui index.html page.
EX: if you use     "http://{servername}:{port}/{App-Context}/{url-pattern}/swagger.json" for generated swagger doc, then the same has to use in index.html as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  var url = window.location.search.match(/url=([^&]+)/);
  if (url && url.length > 1) {
    url = decodeURIComponent(url[1]);
  } else {
    url = "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json";// you need to change this url to your's url http://{servername}:{port}/{App-Context}/{url-pattern}/swagger.json
  }
```

Please let me know If this can helps you, Thanks.

Comment: swagger-ui works. My question is why the Response Model column is empty (cf screenshot), I was expecting to see `Error`

Comment: Make sure to use in the swagger annotations in your rest resource class and the model class as     @ApiOperation(value = "...",  notes = "...", response = ResponseObj.class)  @ApiModel(value = "LeaflicenseInfoResponse")
public class ResponseObj {
    private String code;
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "code", notes = "...    }

Comment: It seems that annotations are fine regarding the extract of the doc generated

Comment: can you see the definitions from the extract of the doc generated ? as shown below "definitions": {
    "ResponseObj": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "code": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "code"
        }},

Comment: I've edited my question with the definitions part. Seems good for me.